# style tag in html magic block not working in Jupyter notebook

Tags: css, jupyter

I'm trying to use a Jupyter notebook to teach HTML and CSS. I can create an HTML block in a Jupyter notebook with `%%html`. However, when I try to include a  SOME CSS  tag the CSS doesn't take effect. (I can use embedded CSS).

#### EXAMPLE that works

The following works and the content is displayed as an h1 and the color is blue:

```
%%html
<h1 style="color=blue;">Hello</h1>
```

#### EXAMPLE that does NOT work

The following does NOT work.
The content IS displayed as an h1 BUT the color is NOT blue:

```
%%html
<style>
    h1: { background-color: yellow; }
</style>
<h1>hello</h1>
```

#### Other things that I've tried

None of the following work either:

I tried using type="text/css"

```
%%html
<style type="text/css">
    h1: { background-color: yellow; }
</style>
<h1>hello</h1>
```

I tried using the --isolated option

```
%%html --isolated
<style type="text/css">
    h1: { background-color: yellow; }
</style>
<h1>hello</h1>
```

I tried using an entire HTML document.

```
%%html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        h1: { color: blue; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using the IPython HTML function - the CSS in the  tag doesn't get rendered.

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("""
<style>h1: { color: blue; }
</style>
<h1>hello</h1>
""")
```

#### To sum up:

Is there any way I can use a Jupyter notebook to teach CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in your css,
you have add : after h1

h1 : { ... }

```html
%%html
<style>
    h1 { background-color: yellow; }
</style>
<h1>hello</h1>
```